# upload a file using gwt with out showing the file chooser,send file by picking it from default location

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I'm beginner to GWT,I've a task that I need to upload a file to the server 
but the constraint here is, we should not show the file chooser dialogbox.

with the given input file name we pick that file from the default file location and uploads it.
I think the requirement is clear to you..Please help me on this.

thank you

Comment: Browsers don't have access to user's file system. So there is no such thing as "default file location".

Comment: Not possible. This sort of browser feature would allow all kinds of hacking attempts and hence its not provided.

Comment: How about HTML5 file api? Browsers do have access to users's file system.

Answer (score 2):

`FileUpload` is the widget in GWT for uploading file but you have to choose a file. [follow this](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html).

There is no way in GWT to get file in client. If you don't want to choose a file from a default location then just give a text box and read file name, then pass this file name to server and do enough processing there, you can't take File in client side.

Comment: if we do like this, the file name from text field will be taken as a string into the server,but not as a file, so we cant upload the file rather we are just sending the file name only.. please tell me the process to upload the file by taking its name into a text field...

Comment: @Arun we cant upload using textfield you told you want just a name and will upload from a default path. Use FileUpload widget in gwt and choose file

Comment: From textfiled you cant upload file , it will give only filename and you can choose that file from ur default path in servr